# Retrieve data from the name of a directory in my database

Tags: php, json, laravel, split

I use php and laravel. I have a column named MsgBody. In this column, there is an array as follows.

```
"MsgBody": [
    {
      "MsgType": "TIMCustomElem",
      "MsgContent": {
        "Desc": "",
        "Ext": "",
        "Sound": ""
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your data are JSON. You can decode this using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

You should be able to access what you want with something like:

```php
$column = [
  "MsgBody" => [
    [
      "MsgType" => "TIMCustomElem",
      "MsgContent" => [
        "Desc" => "",
        "Data" => "{\"conversationDesc\":\"abc\"}",
        "Ext" => "",
        "Sound" => ""
      ]
    ]
  ]
];

$firstMessageContent = $column["MsgBody"][0]["MsgContent"];
$decodedData = json_decode($firstMessageContent["Data"], true);
$conversationDesc = $decodedData["conversationDesc"];

assert($conversationDesc === "abc");
```